# How to include custom js script in ionic 2

Tags: javascript, gulp, ionic2, typescript2.0

I have a bunch of javascript files that I would like to include in my Ionic 2 application. 
I know if it's added to the index.html file it doesn't get bundled into the build folder. How do I solve this problem?
I digged around and found scripts-copy but wasn't sure how to go about it because I couldn't find any beginner friendly step by step guide.

Comment: did you solve it ?\

Comment: No couldn't find help anywhere